# ! Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: subfloats

I need to orient two images side by side using `\subfigure` package. But I encountered:

[image]

I tried the following packages in my latex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{boldeqnitalic}
\setboolean{boldeqnitalic}{true} 
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{subfigure}
```

For another latex compilation I have used `\caption`, `\subcaption` and `\float` for which latex possess no error.

```
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.94\textwidth]{FIG1A}
    \caption{}\label{FIG1A}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{FIG1B}
    \caption{}\label{FIG1B}
  \end{subfigure}
 \caption{a) TEXT b) TEXT}\label{FIG1}
\end{figure}
```

Can anyone please help me to find the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a complete compilable example, please?

Comment: I am very new in this Latex StackExchange and is my first post here. Is it possible to upload latex or style files which I have used? If now then how am I supposed to add the example. Though, I have added the code to use the subfigures in case this is the one.

Comment: You don't need `{.48\textwidth}`.

Comment: With above list of packages and the snippet of the figure, the counting of the figure goes from 1, 2 and 3 for a single \begin{figure}......\end{figure}. Instead, I needed 1a) and 1b). Also, the \end{subfigure}% does not orient the figure side by side and is one above the other.

Comment: You need `\usepackage{subcaption}`, not `\usepackage{subfigure}`.

Comment: @Sigur and Torbjorn, none of the possibility solved the problem. Above snippet of figure code runs successfully for another project and not for the current one. Can it be with Latex version or with the style file? Used version: Texmaker 4.5.

Comment: As doubted, subfigure package was additionally used in the style file. Commenting it and using subcaption in the main latex file solved the error.